# Trouble after uploading .VDH file on Azure storage

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, storage, vhd

I am refering to following article. 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/erezs_iis_blog/archive/2013/05/22/uploading-a-custom-operating-system-to-azure-virtual-machines.aspx

[ I am using Win8, VS2012 ]

I have a .VHD file that contains OS and other softwares installed.  I would like to use this .VHD into Azure to create a new Virtual Machine.  Hence i am refering to above article.

Problem #1: Even after installing Azure SDK for Vs2012 , I could not find CSUpload.exe on my PC. I wonder why its not installed. - any clue.

Problem #2. Since CSUpload.exe was not found, I was just looking into VS2012 and found that i can connect to Azure using "Server Explorer"  and there i was able to upload .VHD into storage area, that i created as explained in above article.

BUT

after uploading .VHD file, from Azure manager, when i try to create a new virtual Machine, I am not able to find my newly uploaded .VHD in the list of Gallery, that as per article should appear in the "My Images" or "My Disk" list.

Any clue, what can be wrong. ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> Problem #1: Even after installing Azure SDK for Vs2012 , I could not
>   find CSUpload.exe on my PC. I wonder why its not installed. - any
>   clue.

I just checked in SDK 2.3 and csupload.exe is missing from bin directory. Though it is present in v 2.2. May be they deprecated this application in the latest version. You could try uninstalling the latest version and install version 2.2. Once 2.2 is installed, you will find csupload in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.2\bin` directory.

> Problem #2. Since CSUpload.exe was not found, I was just looking into
>   VS2012 and found that i can connect to Azure using "Server Explorer"
>   and there i was able to upload .VHD into storage area, that i created
>   as explained in above article.

In order for you to create a VM from a VHD file, the file must be uploaded as a `Page` blob. Files uploaded via Visual Studio Server Explorer are saved as `Block` blob. You may want to try and use another tool which supports uploading files as page blobs. Do take a look at [`AzCopy`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/04/01/azcopy-using-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx) (I haven't tried it personally but I think it supports uploading page blobs).

Comment: Thanks Gaurav.  Problem #2:  I check AzCopy, but it seems to allow copy from one http storage to another http storage.  I need to upload from local hdd to azure.  but i shall still check if while copying it changes metadata from Block blob to Page Blob.

Comment: You can't change the blob type after it has been uploaded. You'll have to do a fresh upload. HTH.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, do you have any idea on doing the same with Operating systems like OpenBSD.vhd ?  I guess the procedure remains same or there would be some change ?

Comment: The procedure would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least use the PowerShell module for Azure for this, the cmdlet is Add-AzureVMImage. Cmdlet documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495163.aspx.